# Javascript closest/next sibling of type

Tags: javascript

When I click span I want to get the next ul. I can do it by chaining nextSiblings, but that will break if I update and add more tags after the span in the future. Closest seems a good bet but it only works with ancestors.

Is it possible to get next tag without creating unique ids for each instance?

```
<span class="dropdown">category<span>
<button>click</button>
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

Comment: 1. you might want to use `.nextElementSibling` instead of `.nextSibling`, 2. just check `.nextElementSibling` until it is `null` or you've found an `<ul>`

Comment: Good idea, Thank you!

Comment: You can use General Sibling Selector  `.parent.querySelector('.dropdown ~ ul')` (select first `ul` after `.dropdown`)

Comment: @StasAmasev This would also work but if there's more than one `.dropdown` in `.parent` this would always select the first one

Comment: do you have any div wrapped all of  these elements together?

Answer (score 4):

You could check the [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) (only returns elements, [`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) would also return text nodes which is not relevant in this case) property until you find an `<ul>` element or until there are no more siblings (`.nextElementSibling === null`)

One possible way:

```js
function findNextUnorderedList(ev) {
  let currentElement = ev.target.nextElementSibling;

  while (currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.nodeName === "UL") {
      currentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>found!</li>");
      break;
    }
    currentElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
  } 
}
```

Working example:

```js
function findNextUnorderedList(node) {
  let currentElement = node.nextElementSibling;

  while (currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.nodeName === "UL") {
      currentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>found!</li>");
      break;
    }
    currentElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
  } 
}

document.querySelector("button")
        .addEventListener("click", function() {
          findNextUnorderedList(this);
        });


// add some placeholder elements
(() => document.querySelector("button").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", Array.from({ length: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)}, (_,i) => `<div>${i+1}</div>`).join("")))();
```

```html
<span class="dropdown">category<span>
<button>click</button>
<ul></ul>
```